Can the Wilson-Fisher fixed point be reached from the massless $\phi^4$ action?
Most textbooks and papers work out the derivation of the Wilson-Fisher fixed point for $\phi^4$ starting from the massive action (in Euclidean space)
$$S = \int d^d x \biggl( \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi + m^2 \phi^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4 \biggr)\,. \tag{1}$$
The propagators are, of course, massive, and the fixed point is determined by setting
$$\beta(\lambda^*) = 0\,. \tag{2}$$
My question is simple: why include a mass term in the action in the first place? Can I reach the fixed point by starting with
$$S = \int d^d x \biggl( \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi + \frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4 \biggr)\,, \tag{3}$$
then use dim reg, and calculate the $\beta$-function? Or is that fixed point different and unstable for some reason? Also, if the answer is yes, how would the known values for $\lambda^*$ and $\gamma_\phi$ change for the massless case?

If by reach you mean following a Wilsonian renormalizarion group trajectory, then yes. But for that $m^2$ must be fined tuned to a precise negative value.

@AbdelmalekAbdesselam Mm I mean by reach that it should take me to the same theory across dimensions, i.e., correlation functions should agree between eqs (1) and (3), evaluated at their non-trivial fixed point across dimensions. If yes, why do people not start with a massless theory? Because one point of interest is spontaneous symmetry breaking?

Whether you have to tune the coefficient of $\phi^2$ to zero or something else to reach the fixed point depends on the scheme. I sometimes set it to zero right away but only when using $\bar{MS}$.
